# Checkbox [checked] directive angular2+ weird behavior

Tags: javascript, html, angular, checkbox, angular-directive

I have a simple dropdown that contains some filters.[image]

when clicking on a filter, i would like the table to show only items with this sub-category.

when clicking on an `li` element, it works perfectly fine and the checkbox is chekced. when i press on the checkbox itself (the input) the table does show the required result, but the checkbox is not being checked.

HTML :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="multi; else singleSelectItem">
            <li class="list-item" *ngFor="let item of filteredData; index as i" (click)="setFilter(item)" stopPropagation>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hidden-box" [id]="i+item" stopPropagation (click)="setFilter(item)" [checked]="checkIfChecked(item)">
                <label [for]="i+item" class="check--label" btnCheckbox>
                    <span class="check--label-box"></span>
                </label>
                <span>
                    {{item}}
                </span>
            </li>
        </ng-container>
```

TS:

```
  checkIfChecked(item, event?): boolean {
    return this.selectedFilters.includes(item);
  }

  [setFilter(filterValue, event?: Event): void {

    if (this.selectedFilters[0] === filterValue) {
      this.selectedFilters = [];
    } else {
      this.selectedFilters = [filterValue];
    }
     }
    this.selected.emit(this.selectedFilters.map(filter => ({ disName: filter.toString(), value: filter })));
  }
```

when clicking on `input`

[image: when clicking on <code>input</code>]

When clicking on `li` element

[[image: When clicking on <code>li</code> element]

Comment: When you click on your `input`, you also click on your `li` element, don't you ? So the method `setFilter` should be fired twice. Consider using `(change)` event on your checkbox instead of `(click)`.

Comment: Well i'm sure it has to do something with propagation and bubbling but in this case, if it were clicking twice, then the filter would be on and then off and the data in the table would not be filtered.

Comment: I don't understand your `setFilter` method, you can only have one filter at the same time ?

Comment: @Florian  yes at the moment we only support one filter at a time. i have made it pretty easy to add multiple filters but we first want to be able to work with one. By the way i have solved this by adding an absolute div that will take the entire `li` and when clicking on the checkbox of the `li` it will trigger the (click) event from the div itself

Comment: Ok I thought you were trying to handle several filters with the method haha ! Your solution looks like a *workaround* but as far as you can go forward it's **fine** for now I guess. If you have time, have a look at `(change)` event, you can capture the `event.target.checked` and do appropriate check.